# CheckBox.DataBindings.Add not working

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, checkbox

I am trying to bind a checkbox contained within a winforms data repeater, however the checkbox itself it not ticking. When binding to a label it works

```
lbSchoolFri.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource5, "SchoolName");
```

Checkbox (not working) -

```
cbSchoolFri.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bindingSource5, "SchoolContacted");
```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks

Comment: Is `SchoolContacted` a boolean value in `bindingSource5.DataSource`?

Comment: Within the bookings table, its a bit. This is being returned as a standard select statement from a stored procedure, which is then converted to a Data Table.

Comment: ok.. so *is* it a boolean value ? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a bit (0 or 1), you have to add `Format` event handler for your `Binding`:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Checked", bindingSource5, "SchoolContacted");
bind.Format += (s,e) => {
   e.Value = (int)e.Value == 1;
};
cbSchoolFri.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

This is a very basic task when you work with `Binding`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: You need to add "true" as a parameter to Binding; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272105/how-to-bind-a-checkbox-to-a-bool-typed-dbcolumn-that-is-nullable)... look at the bottom of the "UPDATE Aug 18" code sample.