# How to populate checkbox ID based on the SQL Server column name it represents

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

SQL Server table:

```
Name        Type1       Type2       Type3       Type4
-----------------------------------------------------
Lance       X                       X           X
John        X                       X
Mike                    X           X           X
```

ASP.net:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Auto Check" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

<asp:CheckBox ID="Type1" runat="server" /> Type1
<asp:CheckBox ID="Type2" runat="server" /> Type2
<asp:CheckBox ID="Type3" runat="server" /> Type3
<asp:CheckBox ID="Type4" runat="server" /> Type4
```

C#:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strQuery = @"SELECT * FROM [Db1].[dbo].[Table1] ";
    strTxt = txtName.Text;
    strQuery += " WHERE [Name] = '" + strTxt + "'";

    using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(gloString))
    {
        try
        {
            sc.Open();
            SqlCommand scd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            scd.Connection = sc;

            SqlDataReader sdr = new SqlDataReader();
            sdr = scd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                //use a foreach by column and check them?
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            sc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I know I can use if statement to checkmark any boxes for the corresponding column with an `X`.

Instead how can I create a `foreach` or `for` statement where it takes the column name and populate the checkbox ID which corresponds to the column name, so I don't have to use a lot of `if` statement.

So, if I enter **Lance** as the name and submit, Type1, Type3, and Type4 will be autochecked.

Comment: You can use a checkboxlist. Run a foreach and if corresponding value is not null you can check it inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < sdr.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        bool val = Convert.ToBoolean(dr[i]);
        string colName = sdr.GetName(i);
        if (colName != "Name" && val)
        {
            CheckBox myChkBox = (CheckBox)Page.FindControl(colName);
            myChkBox.checked = val;

        }
    }
```

Comment: So if the X means it should be checked and blank means it shouldn't, would the above code still work?

Comment: Tried something like this: `bool blVal = false;
      if (sdr[i] != DBNull.Value)
      {
       blVal = true;
      }` but I keep getting this error: `Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.`

Comment: If you're using the string value of 'X' in your database instead of the bool true or false. Then first, I would consider changing that. If the only possible values for the column are 'X' or null. Then changing the column to a boolean with default value of false make much more sense and the above would work. Otherwise 'bool blVal = (sdr[i] == DBNull.Value) ? false: true;' should work. make sure all the code is inside your "While(sdr.Read())" statement and you may want to check to make sure the sdr has data before you try to read. "if(sdr.HasRows)"

Comment: With your comment it helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a databinding on your checkbox for the column you want to bind to, it is faster.

```
checkboxtype1.DataBindings.Add("Checked",Bindingsource~whatever source,"ColumnName");
```

[if it is stored as a 1 or 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145749/checkbox-databindings-add-not-working) 
You will need this:

```
Binding bind = new Binding("Checked", bindingSource5, "Type1");
    bind.Format += (s,e) => {
           e.Value = (int)e.Value == 1;
        };
   CheckBoxType1.DataBindings.Add(bind);
```

OR:

```
//Retrieve column schema into a DataTable.
schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();

//For each field in the table...
foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows){
    //For each property of the field...
    foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schemaTable.Columns) 
    {
    CheckboxTyp1.Checked =  (bool) myField[myProperty]);
    }
```

CheckboxType1 is your checkboxID the binding is then bound simply to column name. Type1
So if you have four checkboxes
CheckboxType1, CheckboxType2, CheckboxType3, CheckboxType4
then bind each one to the Corresponding Column , if you have a list of objects in a datagrid and your checkboxes are in the grid there is a different way to bind for that but similar.

Binding the 4 Checkboxes to your result:

```
checkboxtype1.DataBindings.Add("Checked",Bindingsource~whatever source,"ColumnNameType1");
checkboxtype2.DataBindings.Add("Checked",Bindingsource~whatever source,"ColumnNameType2");
checkboxtype3.DataBindings.Add("Checked",Bindingsource~whatever source,"ColumnNameType3");
```

and so forth.
From your code  question it looks like you want Exactly one row of data.
name Type1 Type2 Type3 Type4

checkboxtype1 can be CheckBox1 Or ChkBillyBob the name of it does not matter.

```
[MyCheckBox].DataBindings.Add("Checked" ~ where Checked is a Property of the Control as a string name - Checkbox in this case has property Checked.
[MyCheckBox].DataBindings.Add("Checked", BindingSource ~ where binding source is your reader ; you should not need to iterate it unless you are expecting more than one result back. the while(sdr.Read()) can go just use the DataReader returned.
[MyCheckBox].DataBindings.Add("Checked",Bindingsource~whatever source,"ColumnNameType1" ~ ColumnNameType1 is the name of your column as a string hence it is in quotes'.
```

As I said if you have a list of objects - that works a bit differently but very similar. Your  expected result / purpose is not stated completely.

Comment: I still have to specify each individual checkbox ID?

Comment: Look at Gregs answer I think it is more clear and a complete code example.