# Checkbox databinding default value null

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, data-binding

I am databinding a checkbox to a bindingsource, if i dont click the checkbox it will return a null value to my database.

This is the databinding code:

```
 checkGehuwd.DataBindings.Add("Checked", PersonenBindingSource, "gehuwd", true,
            DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

how do i return a default value of false?

Greetings Andy

Comment: Why not setting default value false at db?

Comment: i tried that it is still setting it as null.

Comment: is `gehund` a nullable bool?

Comment: its a integer value in a sqlite database, linked to a dataset, linked to a bindingsource, databound to a checkbox.

Comment: I don't know what happens when you bind a non-boolean to a checkbox, maybe [you need to handle the format event as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145749/checkbox-databindings-add-not-working)

Comment: Still inserting nulls, giving me invalidformatexception when trying to load the data after the insert

Comment: Setting it to Not Null setting On conflict replace seems to have done it, seems to mee this is realy not the preffered way of handling this

Comment: I don't think binding non-boolean to check box is preferred either but whatever works.

Comment: But SQLite does not support a boolean type, so we have to use INT but thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use data-binding to [`CheckState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property this way:

```
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", bs, "DataFieldName", true,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, CheckState.Indeterminate);
```

This way, when the value of filed in the data source is null, `CheckState.Indeterminate` will be shown in UI.

**Note**

- If you want the default value of column be `0` or unchecked, then set the `DefaultValue` of `DataColumn` to `0`.
- If you want to let the user also set value of the field to null, it's enough to set [`ThreeState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkbox.threestate?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property of `CheckBox` to true.

**Example**

```
dt = new DataTable();
var c1 = dt.Columns.Add("C1", typeof(int));
c1.AllowDBNull = true;

//Uncomment the next statement if you want default value be 0 = unchecked
//c1.DefaultValue = 0;

//Uncomment the next statement if you want to allow the user to set value to null
//checkBox1.ThreeState = true;

var bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dt;
checkBox1.DataBindings.Add("CheckState", bs, "C1", true,
    DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged, CheckState.Indeterminate);
this.bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bs;
```

Comment: This will still insert nulls when i do not click it, even when setting CheckState.true as default

Comment: It will insert 1 when you click on check mark and make the checkbox show check mark. Inserts 0 when you click and uncheck. Inserts null when you click and set the checkbox to indeterminate which shows a square in checkbox.

Comment: To test it, simply use the code which I provided in example. Such code could be simply tested without need to any database.

Comment: Make sure you read the **Note** part and comments in example.

Comment: It seems the post answers your question, let me know if you have any question about the answer or if you find it useful :)